# How to create a function using conditional data transfer?

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, data-transfer

My code is as follows:
    int cread(int *xp) 
    {
       return (xp ? *xp : 0);
    }

using gcc I get assembly code without conditional data transfer and I know that is because  it could attempt to read from a null address.So how can I get assembly code using conditional data transfer by modifying the original code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the possibility of dereferencing a null pointer then. Make sure the pointer is valid before you dereference it. For example:

```c
int cread(int *xp)
{
    static const int zero = 0;
    return *(xp ? xp : &zero);
}
```

My compiler generates the following code (others may vary):

```
movl    4(%esp), %eax
movl    $zero.1723, %edx
testl   %eax, %eax
cmove   %edx, %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
ret
```